# Oracle 10g A cursor with parameter Error

Tags: oracle

I can't understand why do I get this error. I have the table but the code sample is not  working properly. What's the problem here?

```
DECLARE 
    CURSOR c_cust(p_city VARCHAR2) IS 
        SELECT * FROM cust WHERE cust.city=p_city;
    v_cust c_cust%ROWTYPE;  
    v_city c_cust%TYPE;
BEGIN
    v_city := 'London';
    OPEN c_cust (v_city);
    LOOP
        FETCH c_cust INTO v_cust;
        EXIT WHEN (c_cust%NOTFOUND);
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE (v_cust.cname || ' has ' || v_cust.rating);
    END LOOP;
    IF (c_cust%ISOPEN) THEN CLOSE c_cust;
END;
```

> ORA-06550: line 15, column 4: PLS-00103: 
>   Encountered the symbol ";"
>   when expecting one of the following:    if
>
> 1. DECLARE
> 2. CURSOR c_cust(p_city VARCHAR2) IS
> 3. SELECT * FROM cust WHERE cust.city=p_city;**

Comment: "*Oracle not working properly*" is quite a statement...

Comment: Yes :) Edited the thread name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`c_cust%ISOPEN` should be before end loop;

```
If .... then
  ....
end if;
```

you miss the end if;